# How to OwnerDraw PopupMenuItem CheckMark

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe4

How to ownerdraw a checkmark on a PopupMenuItem?

I tried this:

```
var
  iLeftPos: Integer;
  iTopPos: Integer;
  iText: string;
  iState: integer;
  iGlyphRect: TRect;
begin
   iTopPos := ARect.Top + (ARect.Bottom - ARect.Top -
    ACanvas.TextHeight('W')) div 2;

   { Draw checkmark }
   iGlyphRect := Rect(0, iTopPos, 20, iTopPos + 20);
   if Touch2.Checked then
   begin
     iState := iState or DFCS_MENUCHECK;
     DrawFrameControl(ACanvas.handle, iGlyphRect, DFC_POPUPMENU, iState);
   end;
end;
```

but it draws this:
[image]

Comment: The `iState` variable may have random value in your code. But anyway, you can draw that check box for `DFC_MENU` type instead of `DFC_POPUPMENU`. Don't know why, but the states for the `DFC_POPUPMENU` type renders the `DrawFrameControl` as icons for system menu buttons (minimize, maximize, close and help icon) on my Windows 7 machine. On your screenshot is just minimize icon.

Answer (score 0):

This fixes the problem.  Thanks TLama.

```
if Touch2.Checked then
begin
  iState := iState or DFCS_MENUCHECK;
  DrawFrameControl(ACanvas.handle, iGlyphRect, DFC_MENU, iState);
end;
```

[image]

Comment: That statement with `iState` is useless. One thing is that the `iState` variable value is uninitialized and the second is that the `uState` can be only one value of the `DFCS_MENU...` flags, not any combination. Simply remove that line and pass directly `DFCS_MENUCHECK` to the `uState` parameter.

Comment: @TLama.. Yes I found that too.  Thank-you.